# Appending a char to a string using arrays and strcat

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

Two variables: `string0` and `string1`. Both are of type `char *`. What I want to do is to add the ith element of `string0` to the end of `string1`. Since `string0[i]` is a `char`, I cannot simply use `strcat(string1, string0[i])`.

Nevertheless, I had other idea:

```
char string0i[2] = {string0[i], '\0'};
strcat(string1, string0i);
```

But this results in a segmentation fault. Why and how can I achieve what I want, i.e. appending the ith element of `string0` to `string1`?

Comment: in order to use `strcat()` properly, there must be enough room in the first argument to fit both it AND whatever you are concatenating to it.  if there isn't enough room, the leftover information will spill out of its range and cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Tau Oh... yeah. So... is there another way?

Comment: Calculate the required size and store your result in a variable of that size. If the size isn't known at compile time you'll need to use `malloc()` or `calloc()` to get this space from the heap.

Comment: If the documentation of `strcat` is not clear to you, you should learn about C-strings, arrays and pointers in your textbook. You will also find how to properly write intialisers, etc. It's a basic lesson.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite What's improper about my initialiser(s)?

Comment: @Hanlon: Without context it's not a constant expression. You want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
/* strncat example */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char * string0="whatever";
  char * string1="whoever";
  size_t l = strlen(string1);
  char * str1 = malloc(l+2);
  strcpy (str1,string1);
  int i=3;
  int len = 1;
  strncat (&(str1[l]), &(string0[i]), len);
  //you can also simply do
  //str1[l] = string0[i];
  //str1[l + 1] = 0;
  puts (str1);
  return 0;
}
```

You allocate a variable with enough space hence `strlen(string1)+2`
then copy string1 into the larger variable using `strcpy` and the function you werre lokking for is `strncat` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/) it appends a limited number of characters.

in the code above the result is

```
whoevert
```

Comment: with icc this code compiles fine. no stdlib.h needed

Comment: I use GCC and compiling this code produces an error without including `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Headers have to be included, otherwise it's UB for missing declarations. So, yeah, `stdlib.h` has to be included. And you should always check for error from functions like `malloc`. Said that, the code is overly complicated for a simple demo.

Comment: [Shlemiel the painter](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). If you have already figured out where text should go (`strlen(str1)`) don't go back to the beginning and measure again (`strcat`).

Comment: @toohonestforthissite in the "modern" ( ie not older than 20y) not having to protypes is not the UB anymore. It is just the compile error.

Comment: @P__J__: Yeah, sorry, an undeclared identifier it a syntax violation actually (6.5.1p2). Nevertheless the compiler has to generate a diagnostic message (5.1.1.3p1). A missing prototype **should** be reported only. I have noprmally all warnings enabled, because I'm a lazy developer and don't like to debug code for bugs the compiler can catch automatically. The main problem is many compilers, including gcc, use builtin functions for many standard functions when compiling for a hosted environment to optimise the code.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite it is not the warning anymore (for 20 years). Just switch the C standard to C89 or newer :)

Comment: I don#t see what you mean. Of course you get a diagnostic for an undeclared identifier. And you get a warning for a missing function declaration. Just read the standard. And C standard is C17 (i.e. C11 with corrigendae), so that's what I'm talking and this discussion is about.

Answer (score 2):

strcat to add the char ? Overkill.

```
 char *addchar(char *dest, const char *src, size_t nth)
{
     size_t len = strlen(dest);
     dest[len++] = src[nth];
     dest[len] = 0;
     return dest;
}
```

Comment: Of course, whether it's done this way, via `strcat()`, or via some other approach, it is necessary for there to be available space in the destination array, or else for the result to go into a new, larger array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Firstly - C standard library string functions assume that there is a space and proper allocation is a programmer problem. Secondly it is obvious that caller has to reserve enough space for this char.

Comment: It is obvious to you and to me that the caller has to ensure there is enough space, but experience shows that often it is *not* obvious to folks who pose questions such as this.  It seems safe, therefore, to assume that it also is not obvious to many people who read the answer later.

Comment: @JohnBollinger strcpy the same. It is basic C knowledge. I know that beginners do think about it.